# Android Stripe library causes a build failure for an empty project

Tags: android, stripe-payments, build-error

I am trying to integrate the **Stripe** library for payment with the dependency line:

```
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.17.0'
```

and gets this error when building the project:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-2.5.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.5.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find lifecycle-livedata-2.5.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.5.1).
```

- Compile SDK = 33
- Gradle plugin version = 7.3.1
- Gradle version = 7.4
- Android Studio Dolphin

Comment: It runs fine to me. Probably try to clean and fresh build with Gradle again? Or you can create an Issue in https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues